# Creating Rollback functionality in salesforce

Tags: apex, administration, feature-activation

I am importing some metadata via Excel Sheet in salesforce org. THis functionality comes into play when I click import button through my package. I want to create a functionality that whenever I click on Cancel button. All the objects, profiles, roles that are being created in the org, should be deleted. How can I achieve this functionality?
Or in simple terms, how can I create rollback functionality in salesforce?

Comment: If you are using [apex-mdapi](https://github.com/financialforcedev/apex-mdapi) I assume each web service call will be an independent transaction so you will not be able to do a rollback. What API are you using?

Answer (score 2):

Could you use the Salesforce database rollback commands?

```
Savepoint sp = Database.setSavepoint();
```

and

```
Database.rollback(sp);
```

Reference is here https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_database.htm

Comment: I tried this code. I called the rollback method in the catch block , and initiated the savepoint in the global section of the class.
But I am getting an error saying:
**"You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out".**

Comment: This doesn't sound like the error is occurring because of the rollback, it sounds like you are making a webservice callout. You cannot perform a DML operation prior to a callout. All the DML operations should be invoked only after you are done with callouts.